# Changing pixel size from raster by value

Tags: python, raster, pyqgis, gdal

How to change pixel size from raster by value using PyQGIS or Python GDAL?

I tried to using [SAGA GIS Tool Resampling](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/7.3.0/grid_tools_0.html):

```py
ext2 = rasterLyr2.extent()
xmin = ext2.xMinimum()
xmax = ext2.xMaximum()
ymin = ext2.yMinimum()
ymax = ext2.yMaximum()
extends= "%f,%f,%f,%f" % (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
processing.runalg('saga:resampling', rasterLyr2, True, 0, 0, extends, 10.0,None)
```

But that way not work for me because in the some CRS have different extends order any idea how to change pixel size from raster using PyQGIS?

Answer (score 1):

You can change pixel size using GdalWarp -tr (x y pixel size). There's a sample of what it would look like below.This won't work using pyqgis obviously, but you can run it in OSGeo4W shell that you should have.

for /r %a in (*.sid) do gdalwarp -tr .000005 .000005 %a %~dpna.tif

unfortunately, GdalWarp is notorious for inflating file sizes, so you'll probably want to compress it using gdal_translate as well.

for /r %a in (*.sid) do gdalwarp -tr .000005 .000005 %a %~dpna.vrt && del %a && for /r %b in (*.vrt) do gdal_translate -co tiled=yes -co compress=jpeg %b %~dpnb.tif && del %b

This one should get you where you're trying to go.

Sorry I couldn't provide the solution you were looking for, but I hope this helps!